# implement a tool that uses the technologies - Jenkins, Docker, Docker Swarm, and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, docker-swarm

I want to implement a tool that uses the technologies - Jenkins, Docker, Docker Swarm, and AWS - to achieve a deployment tool that our team of developers can use to manage instances and deploys.
Please recommend what technologies should we (both administrators and developers) be using, what needs to be built and what sorts of machines must be having.
Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too generic to provide a specific answer, as there are different approaches to implement what you are trying to achieve. IMHO the best approach would be to talk with your existing dev team & administrators and come up with a solution which all parties find easy to manage and maintain container based environment rather than specifying several specific technologies.

Each tool you have mentioned has different capabilities and also there are other tools that provide the same features which would be more ideal for your situation. (Thats why proper understanding between Devs and admins are necessary on what you really want to achieve.) .

Since you have asked about what kind of machines you must be having (I suppose this is on AWS env) try Core OS on AWS instances. CoreOS (Container Linux) will be the best option to manage and run your container based environments. [[About CoreOS]](https://coreos.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins can run in a docker container and issue docker commands to deploy new docker containers that reside in the same swarm as jenkins.  You also need to hook into a software repo like git.  Jenkins Blue Ocean is something you could look at for pipe-lining your dev->build->test->deploy->maintain pipes.  Also, Travis-ci, github, JIRA, and Dockerhub are useful components to what you are trying to achieve.